# Change "Request Headers"(Post Protocol) using FiddlerScript

Tags: fiddler, jscript, fiddler-dev

how can I change the "Request Headers"(Post Protocol) using FiddlerScript, for clarification please take a look at this:
[image]

It should be somewhere here ?

```
oSession.oRequest["..."] = "...";
```

But I don't know the correct key for `oRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it by my self: it should be `oSession.oRequest.headers.RequestPath="somepath";` and another statement `oSession.oRequest.headers.HTTPMethod...`